# KStream-KStream Join vs KStream-KTable Join Performance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Application which takes data from few topics and joins the data and puts it in another topic.

Kafka Configuration:

```
5 kafka brokers
Kafka Topics - 15 partitions and 3 replication factor.
```

Few millions of records are consumed/produced every hour.

I am making KStream-KStream join which creates 2 internal topics.
While KStream-KTable join will create 1 internal topic + 1 table.

**Which is better in terms of performance and other factors ?**

Answer (score 1):

The choice is not a question of performance, but a question of **semantics**: what should the join *result* be? Both joins, do compute quite different results so you should pick the semantics that meet your application needs.

The different semantics are documented in CP docs and AK wiki:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#joining
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics